# If $\int_0^1 f(x+\theta(y-x))d\theta \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$ then f is convex

Tags: integration, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that we have $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable and

$$
\int_0^1 f(x+\theta(y-x))d\theta \leq \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} \ \ \ (\ast)
$$

for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  Is this sufficient to conclude that $f$ is convex. I know that converse holds. I have also noticed that $(\ast)$ is equivalent to
$$
\int_0^1 f(x+\theta(x-y))d\theta \leq \int_0^1 f(x)+\theta(f(y)-f(x))d\theta.
$$

It is then obvious, from monotonicity of integration, if $f$ is either strictly non-negative or strictly non-positive we have $f$ is convex. But what if we know nothing about the sign of $f$?

Comment: what integral is this? Riemann or Lebesgue?

Comment: That would be the Riemann integral

Comment: How did you conclude from $f$ strictly nonnegative to $f$  convex?

Comment: If $f$ strictly non-negative then the integrands are both non-negative, and therefore the integrand on the left is less than or equal to the integrand on the right which is the definition of a convex function.

Comment: $\int_0^2 x dx < \int_0^2 x^2 dx$ but $1/2 > (1/2)^2$ and $3/2 < (3/2)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|f| \leq M$ and $g=M+1+f$. Observe that $g$ satisfies the hypothesis and $g$ is strictly positive. From your observation $g$ is convex and this implies $f=g-M-1$ is convex.